# rm -f cannot delete a file

Tags: linux, fonts, rm

I downloaded a font from `fonts.google.com`. I unpacked it to `~/.fonts`, the `static` dir was created. I moved its content one level up, to `~/.fonts`.

Now I can't delete the directory, because it contains an `.uuid` file. What struck me is that this file can't be deleted with `rm`:

```
[ .fonts/static ]% ls -la
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 me group 4.0K Jun 10 11:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 me group 4.0K Jun 10 11:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 me group   36 Jun 10 11:49 .uuid

[ .fonts/static ]% rm -f .uuid
                                                                                                                                 
[ .fonts/static ]% ls -la                                                                                                                                          
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 me group 4.0K Jun 10 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 me group 4.0K Jun 10 11:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 me group   36 Jun 10 11:53 .uuid
```

How is this possible? `~/.fonts` is just an ordinary dir in my `$HOME`.

Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be deleted, it just gets re-created after a few seconds whenever fontconfig notices a change and rescans fonts. (The .uuid files are somehow related to the on-disk font cache that fontconfig builds.)

In other words, that's not the same file in both screenshots. Use `ls -i` to see inode numbers or `stat .uuid` to see the "creation" time to verify this.

Use `rm -rf`, it will rmdir the emptied directory before fontconfig re-creates the file.

Alternatively, move the directory somewhere else (to a location that fontconfig doesn't look in) and *then* delete it.

Comment: What is strange that `stat .uuid` reported a different _birth_ time, but `ls -lia` kept reporting the same inode! Anyway, `rm -fr static` did the job. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, now that I think of it, filesystems *don't* necessarily guarantee that inums will be unique forever... maybe it just kept reusing the same inode slot for the new file.